# Audio devices not working on XPS 13 9320

Tags: sound, 22.04, dell, alsa, xps

I bought a new XPS 13 9320 with Ubuntu pre-installed on it. Out of the box it works fine, but as soon as I run the ubuntu updater, things break. The updater take the OS version from 22.04.01 LTS with kernel 5.15 to version 22.04.2 LTS with kernel 5.19.

As soon as I installed the updates, the webcam, the speakers and the microphone were no longer working. I was able to get the camera working again by applying this fix: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000203830/webcam-is-not-detected-on-xps-13-plus-9320-laptops-running-ubuntu-22-04?lwp=rt

Unfortunately, the audio problems remain. I do have so log outputs that might give a hint of what is going on:

`aplay -l` returns:

```
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 2: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`inxi -Aa` returns:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Dell driver: intel-ipu6
    alternate: intel_ipu6,intel_ipu6_psys,intel_ipu6_isys bus-ID: 0000:00:05.0
    chip-ID: 8086:a75d class-ID: 0480
  Device-2: Intel vendor: Dell driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    alternate: snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3
    chip-ID: 8086:51ca class-ID: 0401
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-46-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

`sudo dmesg | grep -i audio` returns:

```
[    0.166447] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    3.922427] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    3.922556] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    3.922583] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.922692] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    5.162853] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.229645] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[    5.248575] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: No SoundWire machine driver found
[    5.248577] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
[    5.248578] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[    5.248580] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 0
[    5.249513] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    5.249515] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[    5.249516] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
[    5.249519] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[    5.362156] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    5.362161] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[    5.362164] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
[    5.379890] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[  209.846238] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[  209.846265] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[  209.846520] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[  209.846624] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[  209.853414] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[  209.866485] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: No SoundWire machine driver found
[  209.866488] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
[  209.866489] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[  209.866491] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 0
[  209.866601] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[  209.866602] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[  209.866603] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
[  209.866605] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[  209.981422] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[  209.981431] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[  209.981436] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
[  209.981859] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
```

Furthermore, my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` looks like this:

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: I didn't see the HDA codec related information which I expect it should work in 22.04.01.
Could you provide the full dmesg log and the output of the command `pacmd list-cards` and `pacmd list-sinks`? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The metapackage linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 is pointing now to kernel 6.2

That solved the problem in my Dell 9320 and I hope it's going to work with yours too.

The webcam is working too