# On my Dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu Linux 22.04.3 LTS, I'm only seeing "Dummy Output" in my Sound devices, no Audio input or output

Tags: upgrade, sound, kernel, output

Title says it all. I tried everything suggested except a kernel upgrade (currently on 5.15.0-89-generic, according to uname -r) and anything related to alsa, since alsa is not installed on my laptop. I tried to upgrade the kernel with apt, as suggested [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/08/ubuntu-22-04-linux-kernel-6-2), but that didn't work:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for ruomini: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libffi7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Also, no luck using the software updater:

[image]

If anyone has any suggestions on how to upgrade the kernel, or any other way to resolve the sound issue, I'd really appreciate it. I've been struggling with this for several months now and had given up on the problem, except now I find that I need to get sound working on my computer again, or else buy a new one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Audio devices not working on XPS 13 9320](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478908/audio-devices-not-working-on-xps-13-9320)

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the Kernel, let's consider another two methods.

***Method 1:
Using the Mainline Kernel Installer***

Install the Mainline Kernel Installer software using the following commands,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Search for the software, open it, and it will list all the available kernels.
Choose any preffered kernel and install it. It will add the kernel to grub.

[Reference](https://www.theregister.com/2023/03/06/ubuntu_latest_kernel_kde/)

***Method 2:
Using the command line***

Search for available kernels using:

```
apt search linux-image
```

From the results, install any preffered kernel using:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-[version]
```

For example: `sudo apt install linux-image-5.4.0-137-generic`

**Note:** **It is also NOT recommended to use unsigned kernels.**

**FOR AUDIO :**

[No audio after upgrade to 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439064/no-audio-after-upgrade-to-22-10/1439095#1439095)  - use the accepted answer as a last resort if you're planning on getting a new computer.

Hope it helps!

Comment: After my second reinstall of Ubuntu 22.04.3, I found that my laptop is now running the updated kernel: ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ uname -r
6.2.0-37-generic
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ 
As for the audio issue, I tried what was suggested in the link above but it didn't help.

Comment: @FractalBob Did you try after a reboot, in case you missed that?

Comment: Yes, I had. That would have been too easy.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try connecting to my laptop using my Bose headphones via Bluetooth (connecting via the cable didn't work), thinking that the problem might be in the sound drivers and that using Bluetooth might provide a workaround. I managed to connect but only temporarily, so I googled the issue from that standpoint and a user named Victor posted [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-over-bluetooth/833323#833323). I still can't connect to the internal speakers, but this is the next best thing.

If anyone can get my speakers working again (they worked up until about seven months ago, when I tried upgrading directly from a very old Ubuntu version to 22.04 and messed up my system), I'll give them the bounty unless Victor comes forth first. Hell, I'll give TWO bounties, if I can: one for him and one for whoever can fix the speaker problem.

Comment: The above answer doesn't seem to provide an answer to your question. Kindly edit your question to provide additional information regarding your issue.

Comment: @Ajay It provides a partial solution. At least now, I'm no longer seeing "Dummy Output" in Sound settings if a sound device is connected through Bluetooth. All that's missing is getting the internal speakers running again.

Comment: Then kindly provide that information by editing your question.

Comment: @Ajay I already answered my question; see above. No need to edit the question.